# Cerrar instancia ya creada, Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, netbeans, poo, eclipse, jframe

Buenas les comento estoy realizando una aplicaicon con varios JFrames y en uno de ellos hay una ventana de confirmación, entonces supongamos lo siguiente; Tengo:
JF1.
JF2.
JD1.

Instancio **JF2** desde un botón perteneciente a **JF1** y desde allí instancio **JD1** y quiero que al apretar un botón, **JD1** y **JF** se cierren y se vuelva a abrir **JF1**.

El problema aquí es que **JF2** fue instaciado en **JF1** y no se como cerrarlo desde **JD1**

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar el método de instancia `setVisible(boolean)` que contiene cada JFrame. Es decir, que en el método de eventos del botón (Que cerraría **JF1** y **JD1**) deberías establecer con el `setVisible(boolean)` que ventanas mostrar y cuales no.

Answer (score -2):

El JF2 que sea **static** .
en JF1 lo llamarias JF2.setVisible(true), y en el JD1  **JF2.setVisible(false)**
o JF2.dispose();